# GWT direct link to a part of an App

Tags: gwt

in standard "page-based" webapps, it´s quite easy to implemet direct links to several pages, f.e, an url abc.com/app/customer/4711 which directs the user directly to the page diplaying customer 4711.

Is there a way to reproduce a similar behaviour in an GWT-App?

Tnk Mica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Activities and Places design pattern. It provides easy access to any "place" within the app:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while this question is being asked in one form or another and I think misconception exists about what GWT is best suited for.

GWT is an amazing set of tools for creating *web applications*: JavaScript multi-screen user interfaces which run in modern web browsers, load as a *single* web page and generally don't need full page reloads or page switching for their operation.

Navigation between screens happens in response to triggered events (for example, a user pressing a button, a timer firing or server-side state changing). The data needed to be presented is acquired asynchronously via XHRs (again without web page reloading).

GWT provides an elaborate framework for all of the above - Activities & Places for navigation, as Andrei mentioned, GWT-RPC and RequestFactory for data acquisition and exchange, and much much more to make advanced and highly-structured web apps which leverage the processing power of modern machines and capabilities of modern browsers.